# how to select one of several same data in mysql and view in jComboBox java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I have a table01 on MyDatabase01

> Note: in netbeans, id=jTextField1, day=jComboBox1, month=jComboBox2, year=jComboBox3

```
+=================================+
|id   |day      |month    |year   |
+=================================+
|A1   |monday   |january  |2016   |
|A2   |monday   |january  |2017   |
|A3   |sunday   |february |2016   |
|A4   |sunday   |march    |2016   |
|A5   |monday   |july     |2016   |
+=================================+
```

and, how to select one of january and july where day is monday? like this

```
+=========+
|month    |
+=========+
|january  |
|july     |
+=========+
```

then, how to select years 2016 & 2017 where day is monday? like this

```
+=======+
|year   |
+=======+
|2016   |
|2017   |
+=======+
```

after that, i want to view month and year into jComboBox java netbeans, this is my code

> Source code for month

```
try {
        connectDB();
        jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM table01 WHERE day='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"' UNION SELECT * FROM table01 WHERE day='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'"; 
//not work.always show all data, not january and july.
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);

        while (res.next()) {
            String val = res.getString("month");
            jComboBox2.addItem(val);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

> Source code for year

```
try {
        connectDB();
        jComboBox3.removeAllItems();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM table01 WHERE month='"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()+"' AND day='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'"; 
//not work. always show all data, not 2016 and 2017.
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);

        while (res.next()) {
            String val = res.getString("year");
            jComboBox3.addItem(val);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. it will return as you are expecting.

Source code for month

```
   String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(month) FROM table01 WHERE day='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()"';

            ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);

            while (res.next()) {
                String val = res.getString(0);
                jComboBox2.addItem(val);
            }
```

Source code for year

```
 String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(year) FROM table01 WHERE month='"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()+"' AND day='"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'"; 

        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);

        while (res.next()) {
            String val = res.getString("0");
            jComboBox3.addItem(val);
        }
```

Comment: You shouldnt write `month='"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()+"'` because this make sql injection, you should write  `month=?` and use prepareStatement to execute that sql.

Comment: @Numb : here query is called once and so that SQL's normal statement is used. We can use prepareStatement also but generally PreparedStatement are preferred when a particular query is to be executed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
select distinct(yourtable.month) from yourtable where UPPER(yourtable.day) = UPPER('monday')
```